# Copy a form content to a new form that is being designed in sharepoint 2010 info path designer?

Tags: content-type

Is it possible to copy contents of a form to a new form that is being designed in infopath form designer in sharepoint 2010? The reason I am asking is I need to design a form whose content is 98% similar to a form that already exists in a document library.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would simply do a Save As to save the existing InfoPath form template as a new file.  Then make your changes to that.  Not everything (such as the backend fields) will copy over if you do a copy/paste.